# Make sure the presence of a particular character in a string

Tags: regex

I'm using the following regex to parse my application log file to search for particular string

```
\[\s*\b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-_.#]{0,200})(?:\.(?:[0-9*A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-_.#]{0,200}))*(\.?|\b)\s*]
```

This works fine but now we need to make sure that the string "must" contain "-" character to match. I'm confused to add this condition to the original regx.
Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks and Regards,
Santhosh

Comment: Is the `-` supposed to be in a specific location?

Comment: @Trasiva, we just need to ensure the presence. It is not location specific

Comment: I always build my regex queries testing them with this great tool: http://regexr.com/ You can see if your query is working in the real time while making changes to it, makes working with regex a lot easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex matches a string inside square brackets, `[`  and `]`, and may only consist of non-`[` and non-`]` symbols.

You can easily add a positive lookahead restriction after the opening `[` like *check if the next characters other than `]` and `[` are followed with `-`*:

```
\[                                            # opening [
  (?=[^\]\[]*-)                               # There must be a hyphen in [...]
  \s*                                         # 0+ whitespaces
  \b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-_.#]{0,200})     # Part 1 (with obligatory subpattern)
  (?:\.                                       # Part 2, optional
       (?:[0-9*A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-_.#]{0,200})
  )*
  (\.?|\b)                                    # optional . or word boundary
\s*                                           # 0+ whitespaces 
]                                             # closing ]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZ2yL2/2)

And a [one-liner](https://regex101.com/r/pZ2yL2/3):

```
\[(?=[^\]\[]*-)\s*\b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-_.#]{0,200})(?:\.(?:[0-9*A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-_.#]{0,200}))*(\.?|\b)\s*]
```

**Tip**: use the verbose `/x` modifier to split the pattern into separate multiline blocks for analysis, it will help you in the future when you need to modify the pattern again.

If you need to match only if `-` or `@` is present inside `[...]`, modify the lookahead as `(?=[^\]\[]*[-@])`. For a more general case, use `(?=[^\]\[]*(?:one|another|must-be-present))` alternatives inside an additional group inside the lookahead.

Comment: It is a good idea to check for a possibility to "hack" into the code and be able to add other (and the current) restriction via code itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I ran into a situation where I need to check for - or @ for a complete success. So I tried to modify (?=[^\]\[]*-)                               # There must be a hyphen in [...] this line as (?=[^\]\[]*-|@)                               # There must be a hyphen or @ in [...]. But still the expression is not considering stings with @.

Comment: If there must be `-` or `@`, modify the lookahead as `(?=[^\]\[]*[-@])`.

Comment: Hey, this won't work if it doesn't have `[]` anchor text.

Comment: @sln: I know you like talking to me :) The `[` and `]` are obligatory at the start and end of the pattern, they can be called the pattern boundaries. I am not in the mood to dispute about the correct terminology though. Study the original pattern. My solution will work always.

Comment: I don't really care to talk to you about anything, the text is pseudo-anchors, read up on it. The regex body doesn't contain that text and you exploited it but if it didn't, you wouldn't know what to do.

Comment: @Wiktor, here we are trying to pick some text from log file using this expression. The hyphen solution is working. But the second modification to include the @ is not working. I'm using the following lines (partial) from my log file.
2011-02-03 15:06:03,662 INFO  [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@1708593] [               ] (                      UpdateChecker:98 ) New update(s) found
2011-04-05 00:00:02,101 ERROR [scheduler_Worker-6          ]

Comment: Is it logstash? Your pattern does not allow `@` at all. Just add it where it should be. See [`\[(?=[^\]\[]*[-@])\s*\b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-_.#@]{0,200})(?:\.(?:[0-9*A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-_.#@]{0,200}))*(\.?|\b)\s*]`](https://regex101.com/r/vZ7wQ7/1).

Comment: See, your trapped now, have to modify your regex, you can't leave if you wanted to.

Comment: Understanding the pattern is never an exploit. That is an *edge*.

Comment: @kallada: It is 00:50 AM here. Please check the  pattern against *all* your input, I guess it is Logstash, so, you have lots of work ahead. Once you summerize what the requirements are, come back with more concrete feedback.

Answer (score 1):

***Updated answer - Assertion***

In this case, the better way to do it is to use an assertion consisting of   checking only the position's expected to match the character in question.

I know it's simple, but using the *outter* pseudo-anchor text `\[ ... \]` as
a delimiter that cannot exist in the body is a rarity.

You should always try to avoid doing it like this.
Things change, your input could change.
The *rule* to follow in validation of known characters that are *Mid-String* is to use only them
when using an assertion validator.

This avoids the necessity of relying on what is *not there at the moment* ie, not a `]`,
but should rely on what *is* there.

Again, this pertains to *mid-string* matching.
BOL/EOL is a different thing entirely `^$`, and is a more permanent construct
with which to leverage.

It's always better to code smarter.

```
\[\s*\b(?=[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z_.#]{0,199}-|[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z_.#]{0,200}(?:\.[0-9*A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z_.#]{0,200})*\.[0-9*A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z_.#]{0,199}-)(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z_.#-]{0,200})(?:\.(?:[0-9*A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z_.#-]{0,200}))*(\.?|\b)\s*\]
```

---

***Using Conditionals***

If your engine supports conditionals, the easy way is to not rely on a fluke
of pseudo anchor text, ie. `[..]`.

`\[\s*\b[0-9A-Za-z](?:[0-9A-Za-z_.#]|(-)){0,200}(?:\.(?:[0-9*A-Za-z](?:[0-9A-Za-z_.#]|(-)){0,200}))*(\.?|\b)\s*\](?(1)|(?(2)|(?!)))`

Expanded

```
 \[ \s* \b 
 [0-9A-Za-z] 
 (?:
      [0-9A-Za-z_.#] 
   |  ( - )                         # (1)
 ){0,200}
 (?:
      \.
      (?:
           [0-9*A-Za-z] 
           (?:
                [0-9A-Za-z_.#] 
             |  ( - )                         # (2)
           ){0,200}
      )
 )*
 ( \.? | \b )                  # (3)
 \s* \]

 (?(1)                         # Fail if no dash found
   |  (?(2)
        |  (?!)
      )
 )
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have support for conditionals

Answer (score 0):

This conditional would work if just want to make sure that - occurs within your string before running your block of code.

```
if (myString.indexOf('-') >= 0) {
  //your code
}
```

Comment: Can we do the same with regex only?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to have a *single* hyphen, you'll have to either repeat most of the pattern, or check for it in a second phase:

```
if re.match(pattern, line):
    if not '-' in line:
        raise MissingDash('No dash in line: {}'.format(line))
```

I'd suggest adding the second check, since adding the requirement to the regex would make it even more horrible to read.

Comment: Why Python? The regex is  not horrible to read, it is perfectly clear to me.

Comment: They're using the regex with *some* language, and Python is pretty easy to read and understand at this level. As for 'why do it in code', well, it seems likely to be easier for the OP to work with.

Comment: I agree, but the requirement is a requirement. When the language tag is not added, giving an answer for a specific language is like a shot in the dark. Really, this regex is not horrible. It is much worse when a pattern is full of backreferences, lookarounds and subroutine calls (or balanced constructs). This one is a classical linear pattern just containing character classes, groups, quantifiers, literal symbols. A bit longer than it could be, but when split, it is readable.